# Why am I stuck at a version of a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, systemd

I wanted to update `systemd` on my 16.04. In order to access to upstream, I use [Martin Pitt's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd). The version there is `232+upstream20161120-0.master`.

The version I have is

```
root@srv /e/apt# apt-cache showpkg systemd
Package: systemd
Versions:
229-4ubuntu12 (/var/lib/apt/lists/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
(...)

Reverse Depends:
  libpam-systemd,systemd 229-4ubuntu10
  udev,systemd 224-2
(...)
Dependencies:
229-4ubuntu12 - libc6 (2 2.17) libgcrypt20 (2 1.6.1) (...)
Provides:
229-4ubuntu12 - systemd:i386 (= 229-4ubuntu12) systemd-services:i386 (= ) systemd-services (= )
229-4ubuntu10 - systemd:i386 (= 229-4ubuntu10) systemd-services:i386 (= ) systemd-services (= )
229-4ubuntu4 - systemd-services:i386 (= ) systemd:i386 (= 229-4ubuntu4) systemd-services (= )
Reverse Provides:
systemd:i386 229-4ubuntu10 (= 229-4ubuntu10)
systemd:i386 229-4ubuntu12 (= 229-4ubuntu12)
systemd:i386 229-4ubuntu4 (= 229-4ubuntu4)
```

It looks like the PPA is not taken into account even though it is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and part of `apt update`:

```
root@srv /e/apt# apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [92.2 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/systemd/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 187 kB in 0s (638 kB/s)
```

Candidates for upgrade:

```
root@srv /e/apt/# apt list --upgradable | grep systemd

libpam-systemd/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu12 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu10]
libsystemd0/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu12 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu10]
systemd/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu12 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu10]
systemd-container/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu12 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu10]
systemd-sysv/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu12 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu10]
```

I also checked that it is not pinned somewhere, but `/etc/apt/preferences.d`is empty.

EDIT: info requested in comments:

```
root@srv ~# apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu10
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu12
  Version table:
     229-4ubuntu12 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 229-4ubuntu10 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

**Why isn't the last version of the packaged suggested as an update?**

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy systemd` say?

Comment: @Ron: I just updated my question with the output - no trace of the PPA version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the PPA's [published packages](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd?field.series_filter=xenial) for Xenial there is no `232+upstream20161120-0.master` package there. For Xenial the PPA has only the `indicator-session` package.

It looks like`232+upstream20161120-0.master` is only available for Yakkety.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. I guess it is time to update to 16.10.